# How to encode pixel data into a video format?

Tags: c, video, graphics, encoding

I'm using ESCAPI to capture webcam, it captures the frames in form of RGB pixel data, I've stored the RGB pixel data into a file but the file is huge 200MB for 15s video of  320x240.
I want to encode that pixel data into a video format.
I'm using MinGW on windows.

Answer (score 0):

First use any encoder

I suggest `H264 codec` for encoding

so find its library for encoding and encode it

---

Then find any container File formats

I suggest `Matroska` (`.mkv` file)

so find its library for muxing encoded h264 in .mkv

---

**Good begining is start with ffmpeg libraries.**

Comment: Do you know any specific lib for that ?

Comment: there are many open source and linceced version of implementatios are there. You need to google some stuff.

Comment: @ParthParikh start with ffmpeg libraries.